# Communication management in client/server application

Tags: java, sockets, web-applications, server

Let me explain the purpose of my application so you can guide me about the best possible approach.

The idea is building a web application to remotely manage some particular equipments that my company manufactures. These equipments will periodically connect to the remote server to send/receive certain data (through simple socket communication but they don't use Java); this data will be stored in the corresponding data base and will be available through the web application for the different users.

In the same way, when you access through the web interface, each client will be able to see their equipments and perform different changes in the configuration. At this point there are 2 possible options and this is the reason of this post:

- The easiest but not the best option: the user performs some changes and I save those changes in the data base. When the equipment later establish communication to the server, then it'll read those changes and update its configuration.
- The ideal solution: as soon as the user save the changes through the web interface and push the "send" button, those changes are sent to the corresponding equipment.

As mentioned above, these equipments will periodically open a socket communication (let's say every 5 minutes) to the server to send their configuration. At this moment, in order to implement the "ideal solution", the only option I can think of is not to close that socket so I can use it to immediately send information back to the equipment when a certain user makes any changes.

If this application grows along the time, I'm afraid that too many open sockets/threads can crash my application.

Let me illustrate with some code I was playing around. I know this is far from the final solution, it's just to help you understand what I'm looking for.

First of all, I register the socket server during the start-up of the web server (Tomcat in this case):

```
package org.listeners;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.sockets.KKMultiServer;

public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        KKMultiServer kKMultiServer = new KKMultiServer();
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(kKMultiServer);
        serverThread.start();
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("PlainKKMultiServer", kKMultiServer);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) { }

}
```

This is the main socket server class that listens for new connections:

```
public class KKMultiServer implements Runnable {
    private Map<Long, KKMultiServerThread_v2> createdThreads = new HashMap<Long, KKMultiServerThread_v2>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean listening = true;
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000)) {
            while (listening) {
                KKMultiServerThread_v2 newServerThread = new KKMultiServerThread_v2(serverSocket.accept(), this);
                Thread myThread = new Thread(newServerThread);
                myThread.start();
                Long threadId = myThread.getId();
                System.out.println("THREAD ID: " + threadId);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port " + 5000);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public Map<Long, KKMultiServerThread_v2> getCreatedThreads() {
        return createdThreads;
    }
}
```

And the thread class created with every single petition from each of the equipments (dispensers) to handle the socket communication:

```
public class KKMultiServerThread_v2 implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    private long dispenserCode;
    private KKMultiServer kKMultiServer;

    public KKMultiServerThread_v2(Socket socket, KKMultiServer kKMultiServer) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.kKMultiServer = kKMultiServer;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        readDataFromDispenser();
    }

    private void readDataFromDispenser() {
        String inputLine;
        try {
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inputLine.equals("Bye")) {
                    break;
                }
                if (dispenserCode == 0) {
                    dispenserCode = 1111; // this code will be unique per equipment
                    this.kKMultiServer.getCreatedThreads().put(dispenserCode, this);
                }
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendDataToDispenser(String dataToSend) {
        if (!socket.isClosed() && socket.isConnected()) {
            out.println(dataToSend);
        } else {
            this.kKMultiServer.getCreatedThreads().remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that the socket is created and alive I can use it directly from the web application to send messages back to the equipment (Struts Action in this case)

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String sendMessageToDispenser() throws Exception {
        ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
        KKMultiServer kKMultiServer = (KKMultiServer) context.getAttribute("PlainKKMultiServer");
        Map<Long, KKMultiServerThread_v2> currentThreads = kKMultiServer.getCreatedThreads();
        Iterator<Long> it = currentThreads.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Long key = (Long) it.next();
            KKMultiServerThread_v2 currentThread = currentThreads.get(key);
            currentThread.sendDataToDispenser("DATA TO YOU!");
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Do you think it's possible to perform this solution? I mean, keeping these connections open so I can access my equipments whenever necessary (without waiting for the periodically connections). What's the best approach? If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind it clearly depends on how many equipment will be connected to your system. Sockets are not always sending data so it can have low effect on the overall performance. Though, Socket are know to be a little slow, if you have a lot of data to send to/from your equipments, you should consider this.

If you want to have send data from your server to your client you have few solutions

- Your server knows all your equipment after registering for example. When starting you equipment connect to the server. (be careful about local network redirection)
- Your equipment and server use sockets to communicate

I don't think there is another solution but I can be wrong. If your equipment request your server every X seconds, it will never be exactly perfeclty on time.

Comment: Thanks for your response @RPresle. The amount of data to send/receive is not too much but the amount of equipments connected can be large, in the order of several thousands. As you also mentioned, those are the only 2 options I can think of to send data from my server: the first one is not possible because I cannot control the internal network parameters of my clients so I have to use sockets to communicate. I think I must perform some tests but I'd like to have a brief idea in advance to know if this is even possible or it's just crazy and I have to forget about it.